# How do I print every row in its own separate .pdf file in r?

Tags: r, pdf, sweave

I have tabulated data. I have to write some code to dynamically generate some .pdf reports. Once I know how to make R read and publish only 1 row at a time, I will be using Sweave to format it and make it look nice.

For example, if my data set looks like this:

```
Name | Sport | Country
Ronaldo | Football | Portugal
Federer | Tennis |Switzerland
Woods | Golf | USA
```

My output would be composed of three .pdf files. The first one would say "Ronaldo plays football for Portugal"; and so on for the other two rows.

I have started with a for-loop but every forum I have trawled through talks about the advantages of the -apply functions over it but I don't know how to make it apply on every row of the data.

PS: This is my first post on stackoverflow.com. Excuse me if I am not following the community rules here. I will try my best to ensure that the question conforms to the guidelines based on your feedback.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a `for` loop when appropriate.  This would probably be an appropriate use case.

Comment: You can definitely use the `*apply` family for this, too. I would basically just have a function that writes a .tex file by `paste`-ing the three variables into a template string and writing that to disk, and have the function return the filename. Then apply the function to the rows of the dataframe and run `texi2pdf` on the resulting vector of filenames.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Can you tell me how to ensure when designing the document that Sweave only reads the values corresponding to the row on which sapply is applying the function? I suspect that the issue is related to Sweave working in the global environment and not the local environment, but i do not know how to fix it.